# Añadir elemento a ListView Kotlin - no actualiza al agregar al arreglo

Tags: listview, kotlin, baseadapter

estoy he creado un listview, pero no puedo agregar elementos a este, cuando los agrego al arreglo no se actualiza:

**Adaptador**

```
class AdaptadorListaCursos(val contexto: Context, val layout: Int, val cursos: ArrayList<Curso>) : BaseAdapter() {

    private val inflador: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto)

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return cursos[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return cursos.size
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View
        val holderCurso: HolderCurso
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflador.inflate(layout, parent, false)
            holderCurso = HolderCurso(view)
            view.tag = holderCurso
        } else {
            view = convertView
            holderCurso = view.tag as HolderCurso
        }
        holderCurso.textViewNombreCurso.text = cursos[position].nombreCurso
        holderCurso.textViewDescripcionCurso.text = cursos[position].descripcionCurso
        holderCurso.textViewNivelCurso.text = cursos[position].nivelCurso
        //holderCurso. = cursos[position].imgPathNivelCurso
        return view
    }


}
```

**Holder**

```
class HolderCurso(view: View) {
    val textViewNombreCurso: TextView = view.textViewNombreCurso
    val textViewDescripcionCurso: TextView = view.textViewDescripcionCurso
    val textViewNivelCurso: TextView = view.textViewNivelCurso
    // lateinit var pathImgNivel: String

}
```

**ListView**

```
class InicioCurso : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adaptador: AdaptadorListaCursos

    private var cursos = ArrayList<Curso>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio_curso)

        val curso = Curso(0, "Nuevo Curso", "¿Es momento de estudiar otra cosa?", "Nivel 0", "")
        cursos.add(curso)
        adaptador = AdaptadorListaCursos(this, R.layout.layout_listado_curso, getCursos())

        listViewCursosSeleccionados.adapter = adaptador
        listViewCursosSeleccionados.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            if (view.textViewNombreCurso.text.toString().toUpperCase() == "NUEVO CURSO") {
                irAgregarCurso()
            }
        }


    }


    fun agregarCursos(curso: Curso) {
        if (!cursos.contains(curso)) {
            cursos.add(curso)
            //Aqui deberia añadir el curso
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ya estas en el curso ${curso.nombreCurso}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun sizeCursos(): Int {
        return cursos.size
    }

    fun getCursos(): ArrayList<Curso> {
        return cursos
    }

    private fun irAgregarCurso() {
        val intent = Intent(this, AgregarCurso::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que actualizar el adaptador del `ListView` para que cargue el nuevo elemento que agregaste en la lista:

```
fun agregarCursos(curso: Curso) {
    if (!cursos.contains(curso)) {
        cursos.add(curso)
        adaptador = AdaptadorListaCursos(this, R.layout.layout_listado_curso, getCursos())
        listViewCursosSeleccionados.adapter = adaptador 
    } 
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ya estas en el curso ${curso.nombreCurso}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```